# get tab status shown / hidden via event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I've defined kendoTabStrip component as follow:

```
const tools = $("#id-tools").kendoTabStrip({
    animation: false,
    collapsible: true,
    tabPosition: "left",
    select: tools_select
}).data("kendoTabStrip");
```

The following event occurs when tab Expand/Collapse:

```
function tools_select(e) {
    console.log(e.item. ??? );
}
```

How do I get the info via "e" parameter if the tab is Expand/Collapse?

Comment: What info do you want to get? e.item is the DOM element of the tab, e.contentElement is the DOM element of the content for the selected tab and e.sender is the tabstrip object.  e.g. $(e.item).find("> .k-link").text() will get you the text of the tab.

Comment: @ezanker I've updated the question, hope it's clearer

Comment: Still not clear. In the select event, the tab is expanded because you just selected it.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can check if the element **`.hasClass("k-state-active")`**